# Question about zeta function of function field in 1 variable over $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

From my previous [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207885/reference-request-zeta-function-is-rational-function-via-riemann-roch), I know that$$\zeta_X(s) = {{P(u)}\over{(1-u)(1-qu)}}$$for some polynomial $P(u)$ of degree $2g$, where

- $X$ is the set of all places of $F$, a function field in one variable over a total constant field $k$,
- $u := q^{-s}$,
- $g$ is the genus of $F$.

My question now is, must the limit$$\lim_{s \to 1} (1 - q^{1-s})\zeta_X(s)$$necessarily converge to$${h\over{(q-1)q^{g-1}}}?$$Here, $h$ denotes the number of divisor classes of $F$ of degree $0$.

Comment: In your previous question I suggested you look at Roquette's paper http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~ci3/rv.pdf, and here too the result you ask is presented there. It is equation (42), up to simple scaling factors (your $1-q^{1-s}$ is replaced there with $s-1$, and their ratio as $s \rightarrow 1$ is $\log q$). Are you reading any of the references being suggested to you?? Another book-length treatment you might like is Mike Rosen's Number Theory in Function Fields.

Comment: @KConrad: I agree that the question is basic and can be answered after minimal self-study. On the other hand, I would like to defend the OP, who is probably a student, in that only a few hours passed since she/he received from you the link to Roquette's paper, and the quoted formula is on page 49.

Comment: @GHfromMO, sure, page 49 is deep in Roquette's paper, but I had specifically suggested in my comment in the OP's previous question to look at section 5.2.2. If the OP had started reading section 5 from the start then page 49 would have come up pretty soon, and the displayed formula is hard to miss.

Comment: @KConrad: Thank you. I missed your note "esp. Section 5.2.2". BTW I did not know about Roquette's paper until your comment today, and now that I have read parts of it, I find it highly interesting and entertaining.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. From the functional equation (Theorem 4 in Chapter VII-6 of Weil: Basic number theory) we know that $P(u)=q^gu^{2g}P((qu)^{-1})$. We also know that (see same theorem) that $P(1)=h$. Hence
the limit in question equals
$$ \frac{P(q^{-1})}{1-q^{-1}}=\frac{q^{-g}P(1)}{1-q^{-1}}=\frac{P(1)}{q^{g-1}(q-1)}=\frac{h}{q^{g-1}(q-1)}.$$